# How to read TypeScript constant in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 4 application which also uses some legacy HTML/JS pages.

How can I read TypeScript constants:

```
export class Constants {
    public static readonly MY_CONST = "test";
}
```

From my "Legacy" HTML/JS code, assume I build everything using the Angular AOT compiler (`ng build -aot`) which both contains my TypeScript and legacy  HTML/JS:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var conf = Constants.MY_CONST;
    console.log(conf);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

How to do this `Constants.MY_CONST`? Here I expect `conf` to be a string with the content of the constant from the TypeScript constant.

Comment: Your code looks ok. What is the console output?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It depends on what module settings your compiler use. If you remove `export` keyword in class declaration it will work properly.